# como quitar el error de un proyecto recien abierto

Tags: android, eclipse

*Al querer crear un nuevo proyecto o apenas al abrir eclipse me sale error en la parte de consola,tambien sale error en los paquetes,no me deja abrir android virtual,este se queda trabado un buen rato al momento de crearlo*

**No me funciona el eclipce ayuda :,c**
"[2019-04-27 02:47:16 - EcoTab11] C:\Users\Probook440\Documents\Nueva carpeta\EcoTab11\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').
[2019-04-27 02:47:16 - EcoTab11] 
[2019-04-27 02:47:20 - EcoTab11] C:\Users\Probook440\Documents\Nueva carpeta\EcoTab11\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').
[2019-04-27 02:47:20 - EcoTab11] 
[2019-04-27 02:47:22 - EcoTab11] C:\Users\Probook440\Documents\Nueva carpeta\EcoTab11\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').
[2019-04-27 02:47:22 - EcoTab11] 
"

[image: error]

[![*

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

*][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2XZA.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2XZA.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se alcanza a ver el error completo, copia el error y pegalo en tu pregunta. Intenta ponerlo entre ```

Comment: Puedes incluir tu AndroidManifest.xml? Parece que en ese archivo se esta llamando un archivo que no existe.

Comment: Esta linea es la que parece estar dando el error: ```android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"```, por que no esta encontrando el archivo ic_launcher.

Comment: y como la hago para encontrar el archivo correspondido?

Comment: Que archivos tienes en tu carpeta ```res```?

Comment: Ya con esos datos pude formular una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258993/39913)

Comment: el android virtual no funciona,al crearlo no me deja seguir

Comment: Hay algunas maquinas que no soportan el emulador de un teléfono android (AVD), estas seguro que tu computadora lo soporta? Si la respuesta es si, configuraste tu maquina para poder ejecutar el emulador? [AVD requisitos mínimos](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#requirements_and_recommendations)

Comment: si,pero al momento de crearlo no me da seguir o llega a dejarme seguir pero me sale error al abrirlo.

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: Starting emulator for AVD 'movil'
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

Comment: Tienes instalado Android Studio? Instalaste Android SDK Tools, ARM EABI v7a System Image, SDK Platform, y HAXM? Parece ser un error diferente, si quieres podrías abrir una nueva pregunta para este error solamente.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` a `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`. Esto es porque el archivo `ic_launcher` no esta en la carpeta `drawable` sino en la `mipmap`.

#### Resultado

```xml
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Ahora, si esto te pasa en todos tus proyectos android, osea que al generar el proyecto te da este error, quiere decir que tienes un problema con la plantilla que tienes para generar los archivos `AndroidManifest.xml` y que esta solución tendrás que repetirla cada vez que crees un nuevo proyecto.

Creo que en `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates.` (No uso eclipse, no se si este esa opción, así que lo busque) puedes editarlo, ahí deberás buscar la plantilla de `AndroidManifest.xml` y modificar lo que mencione en el inicio.